# I want to write a Q&A: how do I go about doing that?

Tags: support, questions, answers

While I'm rather new to the website, I've picked up quite a bit regarding one particular topic (the Rainbow Servant prestige class for 3.5th edition D&D), and I would like to write this information into a Q&A for other users to read. How do I do that? Just write a series of questions divided into a number of categories in the question (stuff for players regarding what is a Rainbow Servant, what do they do, how to level with them, issues regarding the class and how it affects them; stuff for Game Masters and what to do if a player wants to be a Rainbow Servant, the impact of a Rainbow Servant on the game, how to handle them regarding roleplaying, adventure hooks and so on), then post the answers to these questions in the fields below? Or should I be doing this in another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find real, specific, questions and answer them.

We're not a blog nor a monograph publishing service. When pondering self-answering questions (which we encourage) remember that the questions should be *real* questions that stem from problems you've seen or are having.

Therefore, find real questions about the rainbow servant, and ask them. Remember to cite the original asker if it's not a personal problem you're having. Or, if you want a lengthy discourse on the rainbow servant, start up a small blog and discuss at length. We don't discourage self-promotion in answers (so long as it's disclosed) and you can simply cite your blog when answering questions that the rainbow servant applies to.

Comment: The questions I would like to answer specifically regard early entry, about the clash of text, table, example and FAQ regarding caster levels, the power level of a Rainbow Servant and its impact on a campaign, and how to potentially change the class for campaigns that do not include the couatl.

Comment: And if those have posed real problems, that's fine. But it sounds like what you really want to write is a rainbow servant handbook. Write that on a forum or blog, as those are better resources for long-form handbooks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to write a handbook: my knowledge is insufficient regarding the items that would work best on a Rainbow Servant, and I don't know all spells they can cast by heart. As such, I'm more interested in writing up a series of common questions that might come up for players first discovering the class.