# Is it good to use a Q&A to help other users discover a system?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendation

I'm currently playing a campaign of the game "Wasteland : Terres Gâchées", a french RPG, and I was wondering how could I help people (mostly french, as there is for now no English version) know it, as even in France it is really unknown.

I had the idea of posting a Question about system identification, then answer it myself, given potential readers some information about that system, and maybe make them want to try it out.

**So, is it good to use the self-answer Q&A this way?**

If not, is there a way, in Stack RPG, to help this system being discovered?

Comment: Related: [I want to write a Q&A: how do I go about doing that?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3729/33569); tangentially related (in that the answers point out what to do and what not to do): [Is it appropriate to ask questions you are pretty sure you know the answer to?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513/33569), [What should I consider before posting a question and answer it myself](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/33569)

Comment: Related, on using system identification to roundabout recommend a system (although that's not exactly the same as what's being discussed here): [Can we respond to a closed recommendation question by self-answering another question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6598/1204)

Comment: I'm upvoting this question, not because I think what's being suggested is a good idea, but because you came here to meta to ask about it rather than just going ahead and doing it.

Comment: Related: [How legit is it to ask&answer some questions about my favorite RPG system (that I have contributed some small material to)?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/how-legit-is-it-to-askanswer-some-questions-about-my-favorite-rpg-system-that)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## You can ask real, relatively specific questions (and answer them)

Quoting from [Brian Ballsun-Stanton's answer to "I want to write a Q&A: how do I go about doing that?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3730/33569):

> Find real, specific, questions and answer them.
>
> We're not a blog nor a monograph publishing service. When pondering self-answering questions (which we encourage) remember that the questions should be real questions that stem from problems you've seen or are having.

Essentially, the purpose of the post should not be *just* to advertise the RPG system. It also needs to be an actual meaningful question.

In particular, the method you suggest:

> I had the idea of posting a Question about system identification, then answer it myself, given potential readers some information about that system, and maybe make them want to try it out.

...seems a bit iffy.

Specifically, it sounds like you're proposing asking a system-ID question and then answering with some fluff about the system, rather than asking a genuine question about an issue you've faced within/regarding the system itself.

If you're lacking clarity on a rule within that RPG (or you were confused, but figured it out yourself), ask that as a question - and self-answer it if you think you know the answer. If you have a problem you've faced while GMing the system and need help finding an effective solution, ask away.

But as [wax eagle puts it in this answer to "What should I consider before posting a question and answer it myself"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3142/33569):

> Just be sure you put some work into the question itself. My biggest knock on this kind of thing is that people will often half ass the question so they can post the answer. Both should be of quality.

If you don't have a real question/issue to ask about, the quality of your question will usually suffer for it.

Comment: So if I write a real system identification question, well worded and looking like any other system identification question? Like if I ask for a french post-apocalyptic RPG where there isn't magic but kind of mental power bringing madness? (of course with more details, like [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97544/i-am-trying-to-find-a-specific-rpg-that-i-cant-remember-the-name-of-player-bac))
And why the question should be especially about a problem I encountered with this system? System identification doesn't concern directs problems with those systems but are allowed.

Comment: @Zoma: Part of the point I'm trying to make is that your proposed system ID question is not a "real question". You're essentially trying to make up a question to which the answer is the system you want to promote. Instead, ask actual questions you have had while playing or reading the rules of that RPG - and if (you think) you have the answer to those questions, you can self-answer those questions too.

Comment: Well, I guess your answer to my initial question is No then. Thanks for giving out your point of view. Now I'm pretty lost between your answer and Sardathrion's one. I guess I'm not going to do this Q&A given that your answer got most popularity, and it pretty much might show part of the community's opinion.

Comment: @Zoma: I'd at least wait to see what others think; there might be more answers and votes. Your question (on meta) has only been up for a little over 2 hours, after all. :)

Answer (score 12):

**No, do not use a self-answered game-id question for this**

We don't do game recommendations any more, and trying to "sneak in" game-rec questions as game-identification will just end up causing trouble (game-id's being treated as poor man's game-recs has already been on mod radar for shadiness). This is inappropriate.

What you can do is ask questions about the game.

You can even ask questions about it and self-answer - ideally questions that aren't junk, because it may get people to flag them as spam if they are clearly just trying to get the game's name out there.  Good questions, questions you have had and learned the answer to.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad I asked it on meta before creating the Q&A then. As it's going on the same way as V2Blast's answer, I'll definitely not do this Q&A, thank you for the details addition.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, it is even encouraged to do so. However, I would be careful not be seen as spam: write lots of questions/answers to help SEO and that rubbish. We do not do promotion here.

English is the language of the stack, so you would have to write it in that. C'est comme ça, on a pas le choix… ☺

Comment: I would do it only for this specific system, and I would do it in English of course ^^ It would not be a promotion in the common way, I would talk about the points of the system that makes it recognizable among others system, as for a normal system identification. That's these points that I hope will lead readers to give a look at this system.

Comment: @Zoma As long as it does not read like spam, go for it.

Comment: @Zoma Oh, ping me in the question/answer as I am interested. Would be nice to get some more French RPGs, they tend to be rather good.

Comment: Looks like this Q&A will never be created, so if you want to talk about this system I intended to make user discover just email me ^^